# Matrix of the form $g$ look?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\mathscr{B}_1$ is a basis for $W_1$ and $\mathscr{B}_2$ is a basis for $W_2$, What will the matrix of the form $g$ look like, with respect to the basis $\mathscr{B}_1$,$\mathscr{B}_2$ of $V$? Given from the previous exercise that $g(v,w)=g_1(v_1,w_1)+g_2(v_2,w_2)$

A bilinear form can be written as $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}x_iy_jg(E_i,U_j)$ in which $x_i,y_j$ are the coordinates, $g$ is a bilinear form and $E_i,U_i$ are the respective basis of the spaces. If this definition is adapted into the same subspace we are going to have the same basis $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}x_iy_jg(E_i,E_i)$. If we consider 
$
g_1(x,y)=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}x_iy_jg(E_i,E_i)
$ 
to be a bilinear form on W_1 and 
$
g_2(a,b)=\sum_\limits{z=1}^{m}\sum_\limits{z=1}^{k}a_ib_jg(H_z,H_z)
$ 
to be a bilinear form on $W_2$ in which $H_z$ is a basis of $W_2$. Then the matrix g would be $\sum_\limits{z=1}^{m}H_z+\sum_\limits{i=1}^{m}E_i$.

**Questions**:

Given the fact the answer asks me the matrix form. What am I supposed to answer?

Am answering correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We build the basis $\mathscr B$ for $V$ produced by taking $\mathscr B_1$ followed by $\mathscr B_2$.  Note that the order of the basis elements is important since entries of the matrix are given by $M_{ij} = g(e_i,e_j)$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th element of the basis $\mathscr B$.

Note that if $v \in \mathscr B_1 \subset \mathscr B$ and $w \in \mathscr B_2 \subset \mathscr B$, then we have $g(v,w) = g(w,v) = 0$.  Consequently, certain entries of the matrix will be $0$.  The question is asking you to describe the arrangement of these guaranteed zero-entries.

If we wanted to be a bit more thorough, we could relate the entries of the matrix of $g$ relative to $\mathscr B$ to the matrices of $g_1,g_2$ relative to the bases $\mathscr B_1,\mathscr B_2$ respectively.

---

**Answer:** Let $[g]_{\mathscr B}$ denote the matrix of $g$ relative to basis $\mathscr B$.  Let $m = \dim W_1$ and $n = \dim W_2$.  Then $[g]_{\mathscr B}$ can be written as a block matrix in the form
$$
[g]_{\mathscr B} = 
\pmatrix{[g_1]_{\mathscr B_1} & 0_{m \times n}\\
0_{n \times m} & [g_2]_{\mathscr B_2}}
$$
Where $0_{m \times n}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of $0$s.

Comment: $g_1(v_1,w_1)=0$ $g_2(v_2,w_2)$=0 only if $\mathscr{B}_1$ and $\mathscr{B}_2$ are orthogonal bases respectively, right? That would mean $g(v,w)=g_1(v_1,w_1)+g_2(v_2,w_2)=0+0=0$? However it is not assumed  $\mathscr{B}_1$ and $\mathscr{B}_2$ are orthogonal bases. They can be built if $\mathscr{B}_1$ and $\mathscr{B}_2$ are arbitrary bases which would imply matrix $g$ to be a diagonal matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "orthogonal bases"?

Comment: $v_1,w_1\in W_1$, $\langle v_1,w_1\rangle=0$ and $v_1,w_1\in\mathscr{B_1}$

Comment: @PedroGomes What's $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$?  Again, you're bring in an inner product when no one has mentioned an inner product.  In any case: *whether or not* the space has an inner product has no bearing on this problem, so your observation is incorrect even when $V$ is given an inner product.

Comment: I cannot think of orthogonal bases without the inner product.

Comment: Why am I reasoning wrong in the first comment? Is it because I one of the $g_1$ or $g_2$ can be negative so  that $g$ is zero?

Comment: My question has to do with the following phrase "Note that if $v \in \mathscr B_1 \subset \mathscr B$ and $w \in \mathscr B_2 \subset \mathscr B$, then we have $g(v,w) = 0$."

Comment: As soon as you used the word "orthogonal", you were using the wrong line of reasoning.  Use the definition of $g$ to prove that my phrase is correct.

Comment: In fact, we might say that the subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ are mutually orthogonal *relative to the scalar product given by $g$*.  **However**, this is still a statement that needs to be proven using what we know about $g$.

Comment: How do you do that? I am not seeing it without the use of the inner product.

Comment: $$
g(v,w) = g_1(v,0) + g_2(0,w)
$$

Comment: $M_{ij}=g(e_i,e_j)$, when $e_i\in \mathscr{B}_1$ and $e_j\in \mathscr{B}_2$, therefore $i\neq j$, or $j\neq i$ then $g(e_i,e_i)=c_i$ a constant and when $g(e_j,e_i)=0$. Would it be a diagonal matrix?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}c_{1,1}&...&c_{1,i}&0&...&0\\c_2,1&...&c_2,i&0&...&0\\.^{.^.}\\0&...&0&c_{i+1,i+1}&...&c_{i+1,j}\\.^{.^.}\\0&...&0&c_{i+1,j}&...&c_{j,j}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The first comment you made there makes no sense to me.  What is "$g(e_i,e_i) = c_i$ a constant" supposed to mean?  Your second comment looks more accurate

Comment: Does my second comment answer the question?

Comment: It does in a way, but the notation isn't very clear.

Comment: Also, see my latest edit